# Changing the size of a div

Tags: jquery, html

I currently have a problem with the size of a div.
I would Like to make the Div bigger than its actual content size.
If anybody could help me, I'll be greatfull.

http://jsfiddle.net/58VHE

Comment: Why not changing the css?? The height and the width and height are currently defined there, just increase them?

Comment: yeah, you're not the only guy like this, who thinks too much about the size of their divs.

Comment: @HugoDozois - As this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/58VHE/8/

Comment: Please clarify what you want. Do you want the div to be bigger than the content by a specific amount?

Comment: Sounds like CSS `padding` to me..

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed height defined for the div. Just remove it and it will stretch to the height of the content. Or increase the height if you prefer to define your div dimensions explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the CSS property `padding`.

```
.div {
    height:20px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    width:200px; 
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
}
```

1. Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58VHE/11/)
2. More info about padding: [info](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

Comment: Indeed unclear :P But yeah, you can set the offset of the content and the div with padding. And that's what he's asking..

Answer (score 0):

May be you meant to write something like this:

```
.textbox {width:400px;}
.div {overflow:visible; width:200px; background-color:#f8f8f8;}
p {width:400px; display:none; padding:10px 5px; background-color: #f8f8f8;}
#toggle{padding:2px 5px;}

$("#toggle").focus(function() {
    $("p").slideDown("fast");
});

$("#toggle").blur(function() {
    $("p").slideUp("fast");
});​
```

BTW, your `input` tag migth be missing the closing element `/>`

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58VHE/17/)

Comment: input does not need closing slash

Comment: @Mark: depends, if it's XTHML then yes, if it's HTML then no and if it's HTML5 then yes. Edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: mixing things up, the closing slash was needed for backwards compatibility. now this days, IE6 is not supported anymore. only needed in xhtml strict doctype. But yes, we don't now the doctype he is using.